# transparent .png background

Tags: java, png, transparency

I know Im not the first person to ask this type of question, but I think mines a little bit different.

I have a png image I drew on MS paint that is a player and I want the background of the image to be transparent when I use a graphics objects to draw the image. I tried some stuff with magic pink but It doesn't seem to be working the same in java. Im not new to java, but Im inexperienced so could you explain any packages or methods that you use thanks!

Comment: Are the background image and player image two different image ?

Comment: yeah I have like a floor tile and then Im painting the player image over it so u see the floor around him.

Comment: given an answer below. check

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need to use [`AlphaComposite`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html) to have the transparency effect:
2. Assuming that you already know [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) and `Graphics` uses `BufferedImage`
3. Creating temporary graphics object `g.create()` and then dispose the object for safely restore the state of graphics object changed after the object creation.

   ```
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g); 

       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
       g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
       g2d.drawImage(tileImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
       g2d.dispose();

       // draw player image

   }
   ```

Comment: What do the setcomposite() and derive() methods do?

Comment: `Graphics2D.setComposite` sets the composite we are passing in. and `AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(alpha)` Returns a similar AlphaComposite object that uses the specified alpha value. I have added the link of the Class documentation. Please check them for details

Answer (score 0):

With Java6, a PNG picture should be used for TrayIcon, but as mentioned in this SO question, check:

```
the background color chosen to represent the transparent pixels
the transparency options
the resolution of the icon
alternate format like SVG (provided you are using external library like Batik, and     
conversion mechnism to java.awt.Image)
```